# How to test a python method's capability of handling 2 request at a time?

Tags: python, unit-testing

`_createAccount()` method taking two parameters as below

```
def _createAccount(self,username,emailID):
    <statements to create account with respect to received emailID>
```

need to test this method using unittest, i.e with a single test method i want to send two request at a time with same emailID and different Usernames.
one of the two requests must get the response like already an account created with this emailID.
How to send parallel `createAccount requests` with unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this code will run within a web application, so that multiple requests can be handled at a time.

One way could be to create threads in the test, run the method in different threads an check the results, but that comes with a lot of caveats. As soon as execute threads in parallel, the order of execution stops being deterministic, but instead depends on the scheduler, which can be considered more or less random. That means that even if your method was to fail under certain circumstances (with a precise order or execution), there is no way to make sure that will be able to recreate those circumstances. In other words, a passing test won't tell you anything about the validity of the method.

For this kind of synchronization problem, you have to write the code as to make sure that the thing you don't want to happen twice can't. For that, you need to make sure that your creation/verification code is atomic.

For example, if you're working with an sql database, you could specify a uniqueness constraint on the username or emailID column, so that the second request will fail (sql transaction are atomic). In other cases you'd want to use a lock to make sure only one thread is executing the "check if exists, and if not create" part.

Comment: Thanks, But As i am using MongoDB, and i am using `lock()` user defined method to grab first request and `reject next request` or `notify already registered message` its working totally fine and i tested with two other terminals by sending requests at a same time. i wanna check with   single method/unit test method, is this possible

Comment: You can use threading (http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) to execute multiple codes in parallel, but as I said, it can confirm you that it works in some cases, but can't prove that it will work each time.